# @RequestBody where object can be 2 different class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I have a controller with @RequestBody

```
@PostMapping("/")
    public String doSomething(@RequestBody ??? foo)
```

foo can be 2 different objects. Foobject or Barobject.
I don't know what will the object sent.
These objects are totally different without any kind of common fields where I could use
@JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes

I can workaround this and use ObjectMapper to try to map it to on of the 2 classes:

```
@RequestBody Object json
...
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
Foobject obj = objectMapper.convertValue(json, Foobject.class);
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException ei){
        Barobject obj = objectMapper.convertValue(json, Barobject.class);
}
```

Is there a proper way to do this? Or better said, alternatives?
I know this goes against REST API development, because this should be another method, each with its own object.

Comment: Why are you sending a request body with a `GET` anyway?

Comment: This was for example purposes.I will edit just in case

Comment: Have you looked in to Jackson's polymorphic deserialization?

Comment: Yes, as I say in the question if I understood correctly I would need to use:
JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubTypes

But I can't change the way the request is being done, and the objects don't have a common property where I can filter them

Comment: Have you tried using the methods from java.lang? I'm thinking something like `foo.getClass().getSimpleName()` may be useful, but I don't have an environment to properly test this.

Comment: Yes. If I declare it as Object on the`@RequestBody`, because Spring cannot serialize into a object, it is called LinkedHashMap. 
I also made a parent class, and  the had Foobject and Barobject extend from parent. In this case, the `getSimpleName()`returns the parent

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use, Object, class like this and then take advantage of the function

```
mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Fooobject.class);
```

method throws **JsonMappingException**

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String doSomething(@RequestBody Object foo) {...}

boolean isA(String json, Class expected) {
  try {
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     mapper.readValue(json, expected);
     return true;
  } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return false;
  } 
}
```

Well you said that "I don't know what will the object sent", so you can only do trial and error.

Else modify your request to involve a "Type" or something (I would do this by Making a parent class with only "type" member of ObjectType type, and child classes extending that parent class.

```
enum ObjectType {FOO, BAR}
```

> ```
> Method 1: Use readValue() function of jackson
> Method 2: Do a string search (just to make it faster) something unique non-nullable field about any of the object.
> Method 3: Modify the request.
> ```

Comment: I know that hte object can be on of 2 options.
The alternative you present is not possible since I cannot change the request to filter by Type as I said in the question

Comment: Yes, then trial and error is the only way, you can use Method 1, or maybe "String search" Something unique to that request (just to make it faster)

Comment: Yes that can be an alternative as well but is even less pretty than this

Comment: Think from this way: you are writing an "intelligent" code to interpret the request sent to you. A bytestream. So you have to write some logic for that. There is no "Clean" way here. As RequestBody etc all Map to a specified Object classes you define.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with Jackson.
Create parent class, and both objects extend from parent.
On the parent added:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Foobject.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Barobject.class),,
})
```

This works pretty well, and I guess is a clean solution.
Also, has the advantage to be done on a Spring layer, where other validations defined on fields of the classes will occur.

That wasn't the case with other solutions.